# Googletest usage

Tags: c++, googletest

I want to use gtest/gmock for TDD for my project, but can't figure out how. I want to split tests for each of the classes into a separate module, but that doesn't work, because the project can only have 1 main() function.

Given:
'lib' project, that produces a lib.
'main' project, that has the main() function of my application, that does the useful stuff.
'test' project, that links to the 'lib' project and I want to have all unit tests in this project.

My problem is that the 'test' project can only have 1 main() function, that runs all tests, but I want to have 1 main() function in each of the modules.
For example, my 'lib' project has classes Foo and Bar, I want to test those classes independently, having tests for Foo in foo_test.cc and tests for Bar in bar_test.cc. As far as I understand, each of the modules {foo_test.cc, bar_test.cc} needs to have a main() that runs its tests, but the project can only have 1 main() function.

Please let me know if any of my assumptions are wrong. I'd be surprised if there was no easy way to test each of the classes independently. As I have ~20 classes, creating 20 test projects is not an option.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be exactly one `main` function in a C++ program. So if you
want one gtest test-runner for each class `Foo`, `Bar`,... that you want to test then you
must write a separate test-runner program for each of `Foo`, `Bar`, ... etc.

The test-runner for class `Foo` must compile only tests of class `Foo`, so you must
write these tests in a source file or set of source files distinct from the test sources for
any of the other classes. Similarly the the test-runner for class `Bar`, etc.

*All* of these test runners will link to the same library that contains the
implementations of `Foo`, `Bar`,... etc. The linkage of each test runner will
not pull in any object files from the library that it does not need.

*However* there is no need, and it will be pointlessly cumbersome, to write a test-runner for class `Foo` and another
one for `Bar`, and so on, to run the `Foo` tests and the `Bar` tests independently.
With a single test runner for the whole library, just make use of the the
`--gtest_filter=<pattern>` commandline option to select the `Foo` tests, or the
`Bar` tests, etc. Read [Running a Subset of the Tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md)
in the manual.

Comment: Thanks for writing a detailed comment. I assumed that a TEST needs a main() in the same file to be linked and run. Apparently, this isn't the case, any main() can RUN_ALL_TESTS() from all linked .cpp files.